# WPF, DataGrid, ClipboardCopyMode depending on how many columns are copied

Tags: wpf, datagrid

In my WPF DataGrid, I am using this set of property values:

- ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"
- SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
- SelectionMode="Extended"

**Good:** When the user selects and copies cells *across more than one column* of the data grid, it includes the header information. He is happy with that. He can paste the cells into Excel and there is no ambiguity about the columns.

**Bad:** When the user select and copies *a single cell*, he does not want the header to be included. He is likely pasting that single cell value into another application. It should not include that header. (He has the same preference when he copies *a range of cells all from a single column*.)

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it:

- Subscribe to DataGrid's `OnCopyingRowClipboardContent` event.
- Note that the `OnCopyingRowClipboardContent` event fires once for each row involved in the copy action, including the header row.
- When the event is fired for the header row, delete it if only one column was included in the copy action.

I am using F#:

```
if args.IsColumnHeadersRow then
    let isMultiColumnSelection = (args.EndColumnDisplayIndex - args.StartColumnDisplayIndex) > 0
    if not isMultiColumnSelection then
        args.ClipboardRowContent.RemoveAll(fun c -> true) |> ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

**Language: C#**

I just came across this question, which helped me solving my problem, so I wanted to share my solution as well.

---

I only want to copy the Headers, if **all** columns selected.

- I´m using an attached Behaviour, which will subscribe to `CopyingRowClipboardContent`.
- In the Event, I check if the Row is the `IsColumnHeadersRow`
- Additionally I check, if both the first and the last column are selected

(This is not 100% accurate, since a user can select the first and the last column, without having to select **every** column, but in my case it's good enough)

---

My Behaviour:

```
public class DataGridCopyBehaviour : Behavior<DataGrid> {
    protected override void OnAttached() {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.CopyingRowClipboardContent += (object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e) => {
            if(e.IsColumnHeadersRow && (e.StartColumnDisplayIndex != 0 || e.EndColumnDisplayIndex != ((DataGrid)sender).Columns.Count - 1))
                e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();
        };
    }
}
```

My Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <u:DataGridCopyBehaviour/> 
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

**Note:**

The EventHandler also works without the Behaviour! I wanted to use a Behaviour, to keep my MVVM-Design clean.

You can use this code anywhere:

```
MyDataGrid.CopyingRowClipboardContent += (object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e) => {
    if(e.IsColumnHeadersRow && (e.StartColumnDisplayIndex != 0 || e.EndColumnDisplayIndex != ((DataGrid)sender).Columns.Count - 1))
        e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();
};
```